# Regex to Filter Custom Date Dimension

Tags: google-analytics, regex, custom-dimensions

I am hoping to get the regex formula for a custom dimension we have set up in our Google Analytics for publish date. I want to filter the data so I can see publish dates only 90 days before today to look at evergreen content. The problem I am running into is this is how our GA shows dates like this: [image]  Tue Jul 05 2022.